# How do I create a batch file that allows input and adds to a static line?

Tags: batch-file

I apologize right off the bat, I'm (completely) new to the coding side of things and don't really know how to word this question for easy searching for anyone else.

I am trying to create a batch file which allows for 2 inputs from a user and then put those inputs in 2 specific spots within a static URL and then print that to a file.

Currently what I have is:

```
@echo off
setlocal enableextensions
set "input1="
set "input2="
set /p "input1=Enter Username: "
set /p "input2=Enter Password: "
set login=%%a
set password=%%a

echo https://exampleurl.com?Partner=%login%^&TARGET=https://otherurl.com=%password%> URL.txt

rem echo/%%myvar%%=%login% %password%
echo Check the desktop for URL.txt for results
pause
endlocal
```

The text file is created with the static text, but regardless of the input - all I get is the %%a that I used in the 'set' part:

```
set login=%%a
set password=%%a
```

I suppose my 2 questions are - 
What is what I'm trying to do called? (So that I can search better in the 
future) and is what I'm trying to do possible without any external files?

Thanks for the help in advance, it's much appreciated.

Comment: The `SET /P` commands are creating variables `%input1%` and `%input2%`. Why are you trying to use `%%a`?

Comment: @Squashman I'm more or less just building from batches of code found online if I'm honest. I tried removing the 'set login and set password' but when it generates the text file it never actually puts anything but the static data. None of the variables are ever entered.

Comment: To elaborate on @Squashman comment, `%%a` is a for loop meta variable only valid in the scope (same line/code block) of a `for` command.

Comment: The `SET /P` command works the same way as the `SET` command.  I am not sure how you thought you could use `login` and `password` as variables but not `input1` and `input2`.  **Occam's Razor!** Variable assignment is pretty much the same in just about any language. `varName=value`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a quick example to help you out:

```bat
@Echo Off
:GetUser
Set "login="
Set /P "login=Enter Username: "
If Not Defined login GoTo GetUser

:GetPass
Set "paswd="
Set /P "paswd=Enter Password: "
If Not Defined paswd GoTo GetPass

Set "myvar=https://exampleurl.com?Partner=%login%&TARGET=https://otherurl.com=%paswd%"
Rem line below lists each variable beginning with myvar with its value and pauses 
Set myvar & Pause
```

Comment: Hint @DrewgerC if you try to `echo %myvar%` you've to take precautions as the unquoted string will expose the `&` char what causes an error `The command TARGET ...`, escaping the `&` => `echo %myvar:&=^&%`